# How can a fruit be used as a battery cell?

Tags: electricity, batteries, electrochemistry

Fresh fruits can be used as batteries for glowing bulbs, but how this is possible? I mean how can electric charges flow through fruits? Do they contain chemicals like cells?

Comment: You can read about the chemistry involved in a fruit battery at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemon_battery .

Answer (score 1):

Fruits can be used as *part* of a battery.  Fruits typically have a weak acid in an aqueous solution.  Because the acid can dissociate, it is usable as a cell's electrolyte, allowing a net migration of ions from one electrode to the other.

You would still need appropriate electrodes, which contain materials that participate in the chemical reactions to produce the electricity.

Comment: Note that the cell membranes also play a role - keeping the chemistry of the anode and the cathode separate.

Comment: I'm not sure how much that is true in the case of a lemon battery.  Yes for a traditional zinc/copper cell that is necessary.  But I think the lemon battery may not be doing the same reactions.  In fact, you can put a zinc nail and a copper penny in a cup of lemon juice and get a similar reading.